# Putting 10 points on and within a 3x3 square

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, pigeonhole-principle

My instructor asked us to:

> Show that for any set of 10 points choosen within a square of side length 3 units, there exists 2 points whose distance is at most $\sqrt{2}$ units.

He solved it using Pigeon Hole Principle.

---

But I am going by a different route.

What I understand from the question is that for any distribution of points, for the closest pair of points there is an upper limit for the possible distance between them. They can't be farther than that upper limit.

So I start putting the points one by one by making sure that I am putting them at the maximum distance possible from the closest point. Taking the square as $ABCD$:

- First 2 points are on $A$ and $C$
- third and fourth points on $B$ and $D$
- fifth at the center
- points sixth to ninth on the midpoints of the sides of the square.

My distribution for the first 9 points is having the most distances between any 2 points. Now for the tenth point, maximum distance is possible when we put it halfway between the central point and one of the corner points. The distance is this case comes out to be $\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2}$ which is smaller than $\sqrt{2}$.

What I am trying to establish with my solution is that there is a more stricter limit to the distance we are trying to find in the original question.

Comment: The pigeonhole approach is the standard one and the one you are being taught how to use with the intention of being able to apply it in future situations.  As for your approach, showing something about the distances using the method to place the points only proves something about points who are placed following that same method.  It is unclear whether it implies anything about points placed any other way.

Comment: For instance, if you were asked about placing three points on the unit circle (*circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$*), you might have following your "greedy" approach started by placing a point at $(1,0)$, then the second placed at $(-1,0)$ (*the furthest from the first point*) and finished by placing the third at $(0,1)$... but you could have done better by placing them at $(1,0),(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}),(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Comment: Now... Is there a stricter limit than $\sqrt{2}$ which can be proven?  Yes, certainly... but again, that wasn't the purpose of the exercise to investigate the exact strict distance.

Answer (score 4):

Greed is not always the best strategy. The below pattern has $\frac 54$ as minimal distance.

[image]

Comment: As an aside, even this isn't the most optimal way of placing, it is merely a convenient one to show the OP's misconception where calculation is simple.  This, and similar problems fall under the "circle packing" problem umbrella.  [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square) shows some of the optimal arrangements for various numbers of circles.  Also this related question [10 points inside a square - minimum distance between any of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/790072/10-points-inside-a-square-minimum-distance-between-any-of-them).